# How is hash(None) calculated?

Tags: python, hash

On my machine, `hash(None)` returns a value:

```
>>> hash(None)
-2138947203
```

Just out of curiosity, how is this hash value calculated?  It doesn't seem as though this value is based on `None`'s `id` as it is the same if I restart the Python interpreter.

Comment: Is id(None) not the same if you restart the Python interpreter?

Comment: actually both the `id` and `hash` are equal when you restart Python. I'd guess it's just some sort of position inside the Python binary.

Comment: Interesting points.  I didn't even think to check that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It *is* based on None's `id`, but None is one of a few Python objects that are defined as C global variables, so its address (typically) doesn't change between Python runs. Other such objects are `True` and `False` (but these are hashed as ints), or built-in classes like `object` and `tuple`.

The address (and hash) is different between different CPython builds, however. On my system, `hash(None)` gives 539708.

Comment: Needless to say, this is a CPython implementation detail, so you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how *would* one rely on it?

Comment: That is a very good question. All of my ideas are pretty stupid. That's why I only put the disclaimer in a comment :)

Comment: @JasonBaker one might be defining their own `__hash__` function for a class as some combination of that object's attribute's hash functions. If those attributes could potentially by `None`, then it would result in "identical" objects of that class having different `hash()` results on different interpreters/machines. Sounds like a terribly hard to debug bug.

Comment: @ChrisW., no, that wouldn't be a problem, as hash() of that object would still stay same as long as the object lives (since you can't move live objects to different Python sessions).

Comment: @JasonBaker, an example of relying on would be checking it in a test suite. Say, copying it from an interactive sesion to a doctest.

Comment: @PetrViktorin a live object won't move between Python sessions/machines but imagine serializing and deserializing the object on another machine--e.g., like when your webserver starts a Celery task on a remote host. The objects on each machine would have identical attributes (including some `None`s) but their hashes would be different.

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes. That would also happen with e.g. `True` or any object that doesn't override `__hash__`, though. And with [`PYTHONHASHSEED`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) set to `random` (recommended for webservers), for strings.

Comment: Note that the address can change between runs of the same pythong binary if your operating system has address space randomization enabled.

Answer (score 8):

It's based on [the address of `None` in memory](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/object.c?revision=81029&view=markup#l1076), as the [type definition](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/object.c?revision=81029&view=markup#l1978) says.

Comment: the link is dead, you should have inlined the relevant part of the link content in your answer

Answer (score 3):

As `None` is an object, I've wrote a function `object_hash` for calculation of object hash:

```
import sys
import struct

def int_overflow(value):
    """ simulate integer overflow """
    m = sys.maxint + 1
    return (value + m) % (m * 2) - m

def object_hash(value):
    res = id(value)
    sizeof_void_p = struct.calcsize('P')
    res = int_overflow((res >> 4) | (res << (8 * sizeof_void_p - 4)))
    if res == -1:
        res = -2
    return res
```

The resulting hashes are equal:

```
>>> hash(None)
492116
>>> object_hash(None)
492116L
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Python v3.12.0a4 and [CPython PR #99541](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/99541), the hash value of `None` is now contant.