# Why does hash(None) change across different platforms and in different calls?

Tags: python, hash, python-internals

I'm facing a really weird behavior with the hash function on Python. When I run the following command on Mac OS (10.10) I get different values from different calls.

```
$ python -c "print hash(None)"
-9223372036579216774
$ python -c "print hash(None)"
-9223372036582852230
```

In the other hand when I run the same thing on Ubuntu 14.04 I get:

```
$ python -c "print hash(None)"
596615
$ python -c "print hash(None)"
596615
```

For me it looks like, in OS X, python is using the memory address somehow and Ubuntu is not. From that I can see that the hash function is probably implementation dependent. But shouldn't it be based on the "value" of None only? What do those numbers represent? Why does it behave differently even on the same python version but on different OS?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7681786/1639625

Comment: Which version(s) of Python?

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks, I saw this. But it doesn't tell me why it behaves different on both operating systems.

Comment: I think this has to do with the hash collision security thing? See this: http://bugs.python.org/issue13703

Comment: @jonrsharpe python 2.7.6 both

Comment: That's why I said "related" and not "duplicate". ;-) BTW, for me it produces the same hash every time I run it (did not try rebooting, though), for both Python 2.6 and 3.1, but the hash for 2.6 and 3.1 is different. Running an old Debian 6 LTS

Comment: @tobias_k the difference is probably due to [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: Arch Linux here -- python 2.7.10 and python 3.4.3 both return different numbers on each execution of this command.

Comment: I tested with python3 now, I got the same values across calls on OS X. Same thing on Ubuntu. But the values are all different from OS and python versions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no real purpose. The hash value of an object is an implementation detail and subject to change between different implementations of Python, versions, platforms and usually even runs. Relying on some hash value is in general no good idea.

Comment: @poke I agree that relying on a hash value is in general not a good a idea but it happens to be very important in the project I'm working on. I'm not giving details on the project but it happens to be essential that the hash remains the same across different calls to python.

Comment: @Hugo, then you should store it in a portable way outside of Python.

Comment: Are they both 64 bit?

Comment: @Vor yes they're both x86_64.

Comment: @Hugo. If it's so important, why are you trying to use a method which you know is never going to be portable? Why aren't you using something like [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/hashlib.html)?

Comment: `def my_hash(x): return hash(x) if x is not None else 0`?

Comment: The value of python -c "print(hash(None))" using python 3.4.3 (Anaconda 2.2.0) on Windows 7 outputs 113024943, then 112762799, then 113024943 and so on.

Comment: @Kay that may solve the problem on some cases. Thank you for the suggestion. But I'm still intrigued on why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`None.__hash__` correlates to the `_Py_HashPointer` hashing function. So basically the pointer of the object is used as hash. For `None` beeing a singleton this is safe to use, but not deterministic. For a pointer cast to an adequate integer type `p` the hash value is calculated like the following:

```
    (p >> 4) | (p << (8 * SIZEOF_VOID_P - 4))
```

Referring to this a comment in the source code states:

> bottom 3 or 4 bits are likely to be 0; rotate y by 4 to avoid excessive hash collisions for dicts and sets